# Integer overflow for large a Fibonnaci sequence despite using Long primitive type and Big Integer

Tags: java, long-integer, biginteger, integer-overflow, bigint

I'm making a program to print nth Fibonacci Number.

Method *FIBBO(int n)* uses a combination of long and BigInteger types to store the result of Fibonacci operations. The method is suppose to switch over to using BigInteger when it is deemed that **prev+next>Long.MAX_VALUE** using **big_flag**. However this program only works if i use Integer.MAX_VALUE in the 2nd loop.

When i use Long.MAX_VALUE, the 2nd loop of big_flag is never triggered  now matter how large the value of n and i only get garbage values. I can't understand why my overflow logic is never activated when i use Long.MAX_VALUE.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class fibbo_iteration{
    public static void main(String argss[])
    {
        BigInteger result;                      
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=0;                                
        System.out.println("Enter number of terms for fibbonacci sequence");
        n=input.nextInt();
        if(n<0){
            System.out.println("Fibbonaci sequence cannot be generated for the entered negative value");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        
        result=fibbo_iteration.FIBBO(n);        //call
        System.out.println(result.toString());  
    }
    static BigInteger FIBBO(int n)
    {
        // variables
        long sum=0L,prev=0L,next=1L;
        BigInteger big_prev=new BigInteger("0"),big_next=new BigInteger("0"),big_sum=new BigInteger("0");
        boolean big_flag=false;
    
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                if(big_flag){
                    // System.out.println(big_sum.toString()); to use when printing a series upto n 
                    big_prev=big_next;
                    big_next=big_sum;
                    big_sum=big_prev.add(big_next);
                }
                else if(prev+next>Long.MAX_VALUE){   // ***The program works abolutely correct if i replace LONG.MAX_VALUE with Integer.MAX_Value***
                    big_prev=new BigInteger(String.valueOf(prev));
                    big_next=new BigInteger(String.valueOf(next));
                    big_sum=big_prev.add(big_next);
                    big_flag=true;  // this is supposed to signal the switch to BigInteger
                    System.out.println("Value exceeds Long");
                }   
                else{
                    if(i==1){   // this if block accomodates the eccentricity of starting the fibbonaci sequence  
                        sum=1L;
                        continue;
                    }   
                sum=prev+next;
                prev=next;
                next=sum;
                System.out.println(sum);
                }
            }
        return big_flag==true?big_sum:new BigInteger(String.valueOf(sum));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The max value of Long is really the maximum of the type. Any calculation above this is giving you... well results you apparently do not expect. A check of the kind `prev+next>Long.MAX_VALUE` is a nonsense. It will never be truthy.

A bit of change that should make your program work is: `prev > Long.MAX_VALUE - next`

If you want to understand in greater detail, you can use the comparison as I wrote it and debug, placing a breakpoint inside the if block. Try to see the value of `prev+next`. See how it goes negative. This is because you have reached values outside what `long` can store.

Comment: Thanks, i can see now how i was wrong. Although, i still do not understand why my logic was working when i used prev+next>Integer.MAX_VALUE ?

Comment: @Gestalt because you were calculating in `long` type and it can easily get values above `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: Small note - Java doesn't have a concept of "truthy", as it doesn't allow implicit conversion of other types to `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Math.addExact(long,long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#addExact-long-long-). Surround using try-catch and switch to BigInteger when the Exception is thrown.

```java
    try
    {
        sum=Math.addExact(prev, next);
        prev=next;
        next=sum;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
    catch(ArithmeticException overflow)//Out of range
    {
        big_prev=new BigInteger(String.valueOf(prev));
        big_next=new BigInteger(String.valueOf(next));
        big_sum=big_prev.add(big_next);
        big_flag=true;  // this is supposed to signal the switch to BigInteger
        System.out.println("Value exceeds Long");
    }
```

This snippet should be placed in the `else` block corresponding to `if(big_flag)`.

Also see [Integer Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Comment: That's a very useful method, exactly what i had in mind when i started writing this, although i looked for it in the Long Wrapper class and didn't find it. Thanks.

Comment: This is called `Expection handling` or `coding by exception`. Coding so that you have a normal program flow trigger an exception only so that you can navigate to the next block is an antipattern for a good reason.

Comment: Integer Overflow **is** an Exceptional situation and the `catch` block is there to handle that. Note that the program in the question has an `if(big_flag)` which will prevent the `catch` block from being executed multiple times.

Comment: The "Instead of using a flag," part was a mistake. I have removed it.

Comment: @PalLaden the overflow is not an exceptional situation if you have constructed your code in a way that the exceptional situation will inevitably happen. Exceptional situation means that it is not expected. However, if you DO know you will run into this you are not designing your code well, if you need exception handling to implement your logic.